# Getting more records while joining two tables in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, join

I have two tables, `EMP` and `EMP_DETAILS` which I use in an ETL solution.

In the first sequence, the below query is written to a staging (temp) table, after adding some default values..

```
SELECT 
    EMP_DETAILS.EMP_NO, 
    EMP_DETAILS.EMPID_NO, 
    EMP_DETAILS.ADDR1,  
    EMP_DETAILS.ADDR2, 
    EMP_DETAILS.START_DTTM, 
    EMP_DETAILS.END_DTTM, 
    EMP_DETAILS.CREATE_DTTM, 
    EMP_DETAILS.ARCHV_FLAG AS EMP_DET_ARCHV_FLAG, 
    EMP.ARCHV_FLAG AS EMP_ARCHV_FLAG
FROM
    EMP_DETAILS, EMP 
WHERE
    EMP_DETAILS.EMP_NO = EMP.EMP_NO
    AND ISNULL(EMP.ARCHV_FLAG,'N') = 'N'
    AND ISNULL(EMP_DETAILS.ARCHV_FLAG,'N') = 'N'
```

(The `ARCHV_FLAG` is a flag to indicate whether the record is archived or deactivated)

The 2nd sequence uses the below query to fetch some more (archived) records which already do not exist in stg table..

```
SELECT 
    EMP_DETAILS.EMP_NO, 
    EMP_DETAILS.EMPID_NO, 
    EMP_DETAILS.ADDR1, 
    EMP_DETAILS.ADDR2, 
    EMP_DETAILS.START_DTTM, 
    EMP_DETAILS.END_DTTM, 
    EMP_DETAILS.CREATE_DTTM,  
    EMP_DETAILS.ARCHV_FLAG AS EMP_DET_ARCHV_FLAG, 
    EMP.ARCHV_FLAG AS EMP_ARCHV_FLAG
FROM
    EMP_DETAILS, EMP 
WHERE
    EMP_DETAILS.EMP_NO = EMP.EMP_NO
    AND NOT EXISTS (SELECT 'x'
                    FROM STG_EMP_TEMP STG 
                    WHERE STG.EMP_NO = EMP_DETAILS.EMP_NO)
```

(The above queries were written by a developer who is longer working, so I have no idea what is being achieved..)

Now, I am trying to merge the sequences, so I am combining both queries using a join as below:

```
SELECT * FROM (
SELECT 
EMP_DETAILS.EMP_NO, 
EMP_DETAILS.EMPID_NO, 
EMP_DETAILS.ADDR1, 
EMP_DETAILS.ADDR2, 
EMP_DETAILS.START_DTTM, 
EMP_DETAILS.END_DTTM, 
EMP_DETAILS.CREATE_DTTM, 
EMP_DETAILS.ARCHV_FLAG AS EMP_DET_ARCHV_FLAG, 
EMP.ARCHV_FLAG AS EMP_ARCHV_FLAG
FROM EMP_DETAILS ,EMP 
WHERE EMP_DETAILS.EMP_NO = EMP.EMP_NO
)A
left join (
SELECT EMP.EMP_NO FROM
FROM EMP_DETAILS ,EMP 
WHERE EMP_DETAILS.EMP_NO = EMP.EMP_NO
AND ISNULL(EMP.ARCHV_FLAG,'N') = 'N'
AND ISNULL(EMP_DETAILS.ARCHV_FLAG,'N') = 'N'
) B
on isnull(A.EMP_NO,'') = isnull(B.EMP_NO,'')
and B.EMP_NO is null
```

However, using the combined SQL, I am getting some additional archived records, which were not extracted using the previous solution.

Is my way of joining correct?

TIA!

Comment: Forgot to mention that cardinality between EMP and EMP_DETAILS is 1:1..N.. An employee can have at least 1 to many detail records

Comment: [Bad habits to kick : using old-style JOINs](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins) - that old-style *comma-separated list of tables* style was replaced with the *proper* ANSI `JOIN` syntax in the ANSI-**92** SQL Standard (**more than 25 years** ago) and its use is discouraged

Answer (score 0):

If all you want is to combine the results of both queries you can use `UNION`

```
SELECT 
EMP_DETAILS.EMP_NO, 
EMP_DETAILS.EMPID_NO, 
EMP_DETAILS.ADDR1, 
EMP_DETAILS.ADDR2, 
EMP_DETAILS.START_DTTM, 
EMP_DETAILS.END_DTTM, 
EMP_DETAILS.CREATE_DTTM, 
EMP_DETAILS.ARCHV_FLAG AS EMP_DET_ARCHV_FLAG, 
EMP.ARCHV_FLAG AS EMP_ARCHV_FLAG
FROM
EMP_DETAILS, EMP 
WHERE
EMP_DETAILS.EMP_NO = EMP.EMP_NO
AND ISNULL(EMP.ARCHV_FLAG,'N') = 'N'
AND ISNULL(EMP_DETAILS.ARCHV_FLAG,'N') = 'N'

UNION

SELECT 
EMP_DETAILS.EMP_NO, 
EMP_DETAILS.EMPID_NO, 
EMP_DETAILS.ADDR1, 
EMP_DETAILS.ADDR2, 
EMP_DETAILS.START_DTTM, 
EMP_DETAILS.END_DTTM, 
EMP_DETAILS.CREATE_DTTM, 
EMP_DETAILS.ARCHV_FLAG AS EMP_DET_ARCHV_FLAG, 
EMP.ARCHV_FLAG AS EMP_ARCHV_FLAG
FROM
EMP_DETAILS ,
EMP 
WHERE
EMP_DETAILS.EMP_NO = EMP.EMP_NO
AND
 not exists (select 'x'
                    from    STG_EMP_TEMP STG 
                    where   STG.EMP_NO = EMP_DETAILS.EMP_NO
                    )
```

Comment: No, I am not supposed to create any 'staging' table.. trying to achieve without any  temp table..